# How to provide good mobile phone number verification?

Tags: mobile, registration, security, verification

I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve a good user experience when a user's profile contains a mobile number which needs to be verified via SMS.

The examples I have explored had the mobile number in a separate screen. Here are some examples:

[Paypal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ACIntroduction%20Paypal)
[image: Paypal confirm mobile #]

[Assignr.com](http://assignr.com/help/referees/sms.html)
[image: Assignr.com confirm mobile #]

I would like to be able to combine basic user info (name, email etc.) and mobile number on one screen and have an understandable flow of how to update and verify the mobile number.

Comment: Do you think you can provide some more context? The question seems overly broad as it is now. Can you provide some mockups of how you're thinking, how long have you come, what have you tried and what did you find to be the problem with it?

Comment: Yes, it's not clear what exactly you're asking for advice on. Some wireframes or some additional details would really help out and give the question a better chance of not getting closed off for being too broad.

Comment: Please describe in more detail or in wireframe what you've currently got, and what you see as the shortcoming or problem.

Comment: Question has been closed as you've not been able to provide the addition details requested. You can edit your question to add this information and then flag for moderator attention to reopen it.